# What happened to Stark's book on the analytic theory of algebraic numbers?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, books

I just read the excellent chapter 6 *Galois Theory, Algebraic Numbers and Zeta Functions*(*) in **Waldschmidt, Michel, et al., eds. From number theory to physics. Berlin etc.: Springer, 1992** by Harold Stark.

At the beginning of this chapter, Stark writes

> These lectures have been abstracted from my long promised forthcoming book [2].

The reference [2] points to

> **Stark, H.M.: The Analytic Theory of Algebraic Numbers. Springer, 1993**

Google yields no result on this, except for the book by Waldschmidt et al. above, and an old (1975) survey article of Stark in the [Bulletin of the AMS](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1975-81-06/S0002-9904-1975-13873-0/).

Does anyone know if this book ever came to completion in any shape or form ? I would love to read Stark's take on the subject, given his very clear style in (*).

Comment: Google Scholar indexes an article by Stark in the Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society with the same name, from 1975.

Comment: I stated this in my post already.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. You are right.

Comment: The book was never written.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating Stopple ?